# Is it possible to add a bookmarklet to a link so that it "changes" the link target?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Bookmarklets allow you change the page you are currently viewing with javascript.

Is it possible to add the bookmarklet to a link so that it "changes" the next page where the link is pointing to?

Comment: Do you have a control of those pages?

Comment: What will be the answer if a) i did b) I did not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a universal bookmarklet working on any webpage then the answer is *big fat NO*! :)

But if you want to make it work on pages you control then everything is possible. One of possible solutions would be to add a cookie to the webpage using bookmarklet. The target page must be created the way it changes its behavior according to the value of cookie.